# How level system works in unreal engine 4?

Tags: unreal-engine4

In a story driven game how can I manage levels. Like the player go to a specific location and after cutscence next level starts how can I place levels more efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

You can use level streaming.

When you want the level to load, use LoadStreamLevel, and to unload, use UnloadStreamLevel.

[Level Streaming Guide](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Engine/LevelStreaming/HowTo/StreamWithBlueprints)

Comment: In UE4, the Level Streaming system works to allow you to have multiple "levels" (.umap) active and interactible in-game. The general strategy with Level Streaming is to segment your map into levels that hold the relevant objects for a small area, and dynamically load / unload them as needed to balance active actors with performance. As with Israel's answer, the Level Streaming Guide is the place to start.